# What kind of file is the smp_affinity-file?

Tags: linux

The IRQ affinity can be set by writing a bit mask to `/proc/irq/<irqid>/smp_affinity`.
I guess there is a kernel module behind smp_affinity, however, `ls` tells me it is a normal file:

```
# ls
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 0 Feb  9 16:06 smp_affinity
```

So I wonder, what kind of file `/proc/irq/<irqid>/smp_affinity` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about procfs - https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/procfs.5.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs etc.

`smp_affinity` is a file inside `/proc` filesystem. File operation on that file are handled specially by the kernel. Writing or reading - instead of storing or retrieving the data using some non-volatile medium - the kernel executes special function with special semantics instead.

The file would be created somewhere in [kernel/irq/proc.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/irq/proc.c#L366).